# how to test on which TLS Version has https connection established between server and a mobile application ( Android and iOS )?

Tags: tls

Testing for Poodle attack vulnerability.

Also, I could sniff the packet from wireshark and see the TLS version. I want to find if there is any other way available by which I can test this?

Comment: arent there browser-addons available for this task?

Comment: I don't want to access server from any browser. I want to test communication from a native mobile application

Comment: the you should consult the libs your native app is build with.

Answer (score 2):

Sniffing the packets with some application like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) would reveal the information; the protocol version used in a connection is in the [`ServerHello`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.3) message (take care to look at the `server_version` field, not the "version" in the record headers, which may not match).

If you don't want to use a packet sniffer, you may try to modify the DNS so that the connection request from the application does not go to the intended server, but to another computer that you control. On that computer, you can then run a small server software that binds to port 443 and receives the `ClientHello` message from the client. Looking at the message contents, you could see the maximum version supported by the client. By sending yourself the message to the intended server, you could also obtain the corresponding `ServerHello` and see for yourself. Using a packet sniffer would still be simpler, though.

(Altering the DNS should be doable on the WiFi access point, if the mobile connects through WiFi.)

You cannot obtain the information without connecting at some point to the true server, either from the mobile application or on your own; the reason is that the protocol version is the result of a **negotiation** between client and server. The client suggests, but the server chooses.

---

An additional issue is *protocol downgrade attacks*. It is improbable that your client and server using SSL 3.0 by default; it would require that either or both implementation are unaware of TLS 1.0 (published in January 1999 !). However, it is conceivable that SSL 3.0 could be forced upon them. The method is simple: the attacker simply breaks (with RST packets) any connection where the client announces anything newer than SSL 3.0 in its `ClientHello`. *Some* clients will then try again, voluntarily restricting themselves to SSL 3.0. If your application is such a client, then the protocol downgrade attack succeeds and the connections will use SSL 3.0. The problem here is that you cannot know whether a protocol downgrade attack applies without trying it: it hinges on the client behaviour under abnormal circumstances, so you have to force the abnormal circumstances. You are then back to the sniffer plan, with a vengeance.

On the other hand, you might get the information you seek by simply connecting to the server. From a computer with OpenSSL (e.g. any Linux or MacOS X system), try this:

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect theservername:443
```

replacing "theservername" with the actual server name (and possibly replacing the port if the connection does not use the standard 443 port). OpenSSL will try to connect using only SSL 3.0 as supported protocol. If the server rejects the connection right away with a "protocol_version" alert message, then you *know* that the server does not accept to use SSL 3.0, and thus the connection between app and server will never use SSL 3.0, regardless of protocol downgrade attacks.

But if the server accepts a SSL 3.0 connection, then all options are still open, and you are back to trying the downgrade attack.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. It really helped. Also I found this new tool [https://github.com/google/nogotofail] if it can help !